# Element 2 get clicked element 1's id in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

In javascript/jquery,

1. button1 clicked > get button1's id by

   ```
   var button1id= $(this).attr("id");
   ```
2. button2 clicked > get button1id

I'd like to ask how `button2` get `button1`'s id?

Thank you!

```
$(".btn1").click(function() {
    var catid = $(this).attr("id");
}

$(".btn2").click(function(){ 
    var catid = $(".subscat").target.attr("id"); //HOW TO GET BTN1's ID??
}
```

Comment: Uhhhhh, wat? You haven't explained the problem very well. Seeing your full HTML and JS code may help

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$(".btn2").click(function(){ 
    var catid = $(".btn1").attr("id");//gets .btn1 id
}
```

---

I think you're needing this:

```
var catid;
$(".btn1").click(function() {
    catid = $(this).attr("id");
}

$(".btn2").click(function(){ 
    alert(catid);//catid will be .btn1 id only after clicking .btn1 
                 // else undefined will be returned
}
```

Comment: i actually have a lot of div with .btn1, so in [var catid = $(".btn1").attr("id"); ] i can't use $(".btn1") as it will always give me the first btn1 's id

Comment: check for the updated answer....

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(".btn2").click(function(){ 
    var catid = $(".btn1").attr("id");
}
```